# The return type 'LoginPage' isn't a 'void', as required by the closure's context

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart-null-safety

so, if user is null.. page is move into login page

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        AuthServices.userStream.listen((User? user) {
          if (user == null) {
            return LoginPage(); 

          }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You forgot `else return AnotherPage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AuthServices.userStream.listen((User? user) {
  if (user == null) {
    return login();
  }
});
enter code here
```

> then in login()

```
void login() {
Get.to(LoginPage());
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Add an else block

```
else{
   //when user is not null 
   retun yourPage();
 }
```

Complete code :-

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AuthServices.userStream.listen((User? user) {
      if (user == null) {
        return LoginPage(); 
      }
    else{
   //when user is not null 
    retun yourPage();
     }
    });
 }
```

Comment: i make function